# Determine format of incoming video stream

Tags: python, stream, udp, gstreamer, wireshark

**QUESTION**

How can I determine how to decode stream video data with unknown properties?

**PROBLEM:**

For weeks I've been trying to get my camera (HC-V770) to stream to YouTube.

After a lot of wireshark and determining the camera's abilities I managed to have the camera send video data to my computer.

It comes in the form of UDP data but I can't seem to figure out what that data actually is.
The camera will start sending UDP this stream data to requester's device on a specified port after sending it an HTTP request.

eg: calling http://CAMERAIP/cam.cgi?mode=startstream&value=49152 will cause the camera to send video data to my device on port 49152

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:**
VLC won't detect it. using udp://@0.0.0.0:49152 it detects some incoming data but it doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

I've found this script (shown below & slightly modified), which supposedly works for other/older Panasonic cameras but not this one.

The script displays a black window and is responsive to "some incoming data" but doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

It will also stop functioning when the data stream stops, confirming that it is in fact picking up something

```
## the following also needs to be updated. figure it out on your own.
MY_IP = "192.168.0.149" ## THIS IS YOUR LOCAL IP ADDRESS 
THEIR_IP = "192.168.0.163"  ## THIS IS THE IP ADDRESS OF THE CAMERA
RTMP_OUT = "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEYHERE

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
import numpy as np
import socket
import cv2
import binascii
import threading
import time
import sys

## HHTP req's dont work for dick
#do this to start stram
#http://192.168.0.163/cam.cgi?mode=startstream&value=49152
#do this to refresh & check status
#http://192.168.0.163/cam.cgi?mode=getstate
# then run progrem

GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
UDP_PORT = 49152
start = binascii.unhexlify(''.join('FF D8'.split()))
end = binascii.unhexlify(''.join('FF D9'.split()))
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((MY_IP, UDP_PORT))

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

## ## 4K Video Mode = 640x360, but photo mode is 640x480 ..    adust the below line accordingly. It's currently set for 640x360, but will scale the output up to 1280x720.
## min-threshold-time=1130000000 can be adjusted to get the audio/video sink more aligned. It should be pretty close as is.
#CLI='appsrc name=mysource format=TIME do-timestamp=TRUE is-live=TRUE caps="video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=640,height=360,framerate=(fraction)30/1,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1" ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! tee name=RAW RAW. ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! autovideosink sync=false RAW. ! queue  max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! x264enc cabac=true aud=true tune=zerolatency byte-stream=false sliced-threads=true threads=4 speed-preset=1 bitrate=2000 key-int-max=20 bframes=0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,profile=main ! mux. autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue  max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! queue max-size-buffers=1 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=1140000000 ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! queue max-size-buffers=3 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 ! rtmpsink location="'+RTMP_OUT+'" sync=false'
CLI='appsrc name=mysource format=TIME do-timestamp=TRUE is-live=TRUE caps="video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=(fraction)50/1,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1" ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1280,height=720,framerate=(fraction)30/1" ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! tee name=RAW RAW. ! queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! autovideosink sync=false RAW. ! queue  max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! x264enc cabac=true aud=true tune=zerolatency byte-stream=false sliced-threads=true threads=4 speed-preset=1 bitrate=2000 key-int-max=20 bframes=0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,profile=main ! mux. autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue  max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! queue max-size-buffers=1 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=1140000000 ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! queue max-size-buffers=3 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 ! rtmpsink location="'+RTMP_OUT+'" sync=false'

pipline=Gst.parse_launch(CLI)

appsrc=pipline.get_by_name("mysource")
#appsink=pipline.get_by_name("sink")
appsrc.set_property('emit-signals',True) #tell sink to emit signals

pipline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

def keepalive(MY_IP, THEIR_IP):

    while True:
        try:
            tcpsock.sendto("GET /cam.cgi?mode=startstream&value=49152 HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+MY_IP+"\n\nUser-Agent:Mozilla 5.0\n", (MY_IP, 80))
            response = tcpsock.recv(1024)
            time.sleep( 8 )
            print ("keep alive")
        except:
            tcpsock.connect(("192.168.0.163", 80))


thread = threading.Thread(target=keepalive, args=(MY_IP,THEIR_IP,))
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

total=0
while (1==1):
    #begin = time.time()
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(999999) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    data = data.split(start)[1].split(end)[0]
    data = start+data+end  
    data = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8) # to array
    data = cv2.imdecode(np.array(data),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR) #
    #print np.shape(data) ## uncomment to see resolution of video
    cv2.imshow("img",data) ## 4K Video Mode = 640x360, but photo mode is 640x480 ..  
    #cv2.waitKey(1)
    frame = data.tostring()
    buf = Gst.Buffer.new_allocate(None, len(frame), None)
    buf.fill(0,frame)
    appsrc.emit("push-buffer", buf)
    #final = time.time()
    #total = total*0.8 + (final - begin)*.2
    #print "time",str(1.0/total)
print("EXIT")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be trying [auto-plugging](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/autoplugging.html), basically you use the typefind element to parse incoming buffers to determine the format.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that!